# Slow numpy evaluation on function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy

I have a very slow running function in an optimization routine. I previously had some small loops in the function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51338448/multiplication-division-of-2d-numpy-arrays-to-produce-3d-array)), which takes about 15 minutes to run 3 iterations. After making the below changes and profiling the function, it now takes just over 1 hour. Removal of the for loops actually increased the run time. A summary of the largest time drains:

```
   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     2703 3949.306    1.461 4299.286    1.591 foo.py:212(loc_probs)
    24387  230.388    0.009  230.390    0.009 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
     2704   75.005    0.028   75.005    0.028 {method 'dot' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
     2703   44.783    0.017   44.783    0.017 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.where}
     2703    6.897    0.003 4308.789    1.594 foo.py:258(bc_mod)
        3    3.600    1.200    3.600    1.200 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
```

and the complete function:

```
def loc_probs(params):
    MU = np.multiply(arr_nest, params[-1 * NEST_LEN:])
    params[-1 * NEST_LEN] = 1

    # Get the utility function
    v = v_3d.dot(params[:-1*NEST_LEN])

    # Create a 3d matrix of records x alts x nests
    # Take exponential over the nests
    v_mu_3d = np.exp(v[:,:,None] * MU)

    # Component 1
    # Sum over the alts
    p1_3d = v_mu_3d / v_mu_3d.sum(axis=1)[:,None,:]

    # Component 2
    # Sum over the alts
    num = v_mu_3d.sum(axis=1)
    # Divide over alts by MU for each nest
    num = np.where(MU > 0, num[:, None, :] / MU, 0)
    # Sum over the nests
    p2_3d = num / num.sum(axis=2)[:, :, None]

    p = p1_3d * p2_3d
    p = p.sum(axis=2)

    # Pass a 2d matrix of probabilities to the main function (rows x alts)
    return p
```

As far as I can tell, it's vectorized in numpy and should run relatively fast (compared with an implementation using loops, etc). The underlying numpy seems to be using an inefficient process with which I am unfamiliar. I have tried a for loop method with cython, but that gave a similar time to my original implementation (~15 minutes). The actual optimization initially takes 45 iterations to converge (was taking ~ 6 hours), so 1 hour for 3 iterations is not acceptable.

**Edit** Version with for loops (note: MU is highly sparse)

```
def loc_probs(params):
    MU_sp = sp_arr_nest.multiply(params[-1 * NEST_LEN:])
    MU = MU_sp.todense()
    params[-1 * NEST_LEN] = 1

    # Get the utility function
    v = v_3d.dot(params[:-1*NEST_LEN])

    # Fix first nest parameter
    params[-1 * NEST_LEN] = 1

    # Create a 3d matrix of records x alts x nests
    v_mu_3d = np.zeros((v.shape[0], ALT_LEN, NEST_LEN))
    for k in range(NEST_LEN):
        v_mu_3d[:,:,k] = v * MU[:,k]
    v_mu_3d = np.exp(v_mu_3d)

    # Component 1
    p1_3d = np.zeros((v.shape[0], ALT_LEN, NEST_LEN))
    for k in range(NEST_LEN):
        num = v_mu_3d[:,:,k]
        denom = v_mu_3d[:,:,k].sum(axis=1)
        denom = denom[:,np.newaxis]
        p1_3d[:, :, k] = num / denom
    # Component 2
    p2_3d = np.zeros((v.shape[0], ALT_LEN, NEST_LEN))
    for j in range(ALT_LEN):
        num = v_mu_3d[:,:,:].sum(axis=1)
        num = np.log(num)
        temp_MU = MU[j,:]
        num = ne.evaluate('where(temp_MU >0, num / temp_MU, 0)')
        denom = num.sum(axis=1)
        denom = denom[:, np.newaxis]
        p2_3d[:, j, :] = num / denom

    p = p1_3d * p2_3d
    p = p.sum(axis=2)

    # Pass a 2d matrix of probabilities to the main function (rows x alts)
    return p
```

This is the profile for getting the input data from a database and calling the loc_prob() function on a static set of parameters

```
Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        3    3.581    1.194    3.581    1.194 {method 'execute' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
        1    1.502    1.502    1.656    1.656 foo.py:212(loc_probs)
        3    0.867    0.289    0.867    0.289 {method 'fetchall' of 'psycopg2.extensions.cursor' objects}
      200    0.579    0.003    0.579    0.003 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
      817    0.127    0.000    0.127    0.000 {built-in method marshal.loads}
       19    0.098    0.005    0.098    0.005 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.074    0.074    7.811    7.811 foo.py:10(<module>)
  140/110    0.070    0.001    0.102    0.001 {built-in method _imp.create_dynamic}
2605/2561    0.055    0.000    0.176    0.000 {built-in method builtins.__build_class__}
        1    0.055    0.055    0.055    0.055 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
   1249/1    0.052    0.000    7.811    7.811 {built-in method builtins.exec}
```

This is a minimal program (limited to 1 iteration by 'maxiter':1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy import sparse

HEAD_LEN = 4

NAICS_LEN = 9

dat_ASC = np.random.randint(1,32,size=(642878))

dummyASC = pd.get_dummies(dat_ASC, drop_first=True).values
ASC_LEN = dummyASC.shape[1]
ALT_LEN = ASC_LEN + 1

chosen = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(642878))
chosen = chosen.reshape((-1, ALT_LEN))
chosen_spar = sparse.csr_matrix(chosen)

dat_CT = np.random.randint(0,6,size=(642878))
VAR_LEN = 1

dat_SALES = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(642878))
VAR_LEN += 1

dat_AREA = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(642878,1))

dat_NAICS = np.random.randint(1,5,size=(642878))

dummyNAICS = pd.get_dummies(dat_NAICS, drop_first=True).values
dummyNAICS = np.multiply(dummyNAICS, dat_AREA)
DUM_LEN = dummyNAICS.shape[1]
VAR_LEN += DUM_LEN

# Params defined by 30 ASC codes for each alt (-1)
params = np.array((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))


# Define the nests as a matrix to be multiplied by the utility matrix (alts x nest alts)
NEST_LEN = 14
arr_nest = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(ALT_LEN, NEST_LEN))

# Build the utility function
v_ASC = dummyASC.reshape((-1, ALT_LEN, dummyASC.shape[1]))
v_CT = dat_CT.reshape((-1, ALT_LEN, 1))
v_SALES = dat_SALES.reshape((-1, ALT_LEN, 1))
v_NAICS = dummyNAICS.reshape((-1, ALT_LEN, dummyNAICS.shape[1]))

# Create a 3d matrix of records x alts x attributes
v_3d = np.concatenate((v_ASC, v_CT, v_SALES, v_NAICS), axis=2)

def loc_probs(params):
    MU = np.multiply(arr_nest, params[-1 * NEST_LEN:])
    params[-1 * NEST_LEN] = 1

    # Get the utility function
    v = v_3d.dot(params[:-1*NEST_LEN])

    # Take exponential over the nests
    v_mu_3d = np.exp(v[:,:,None] * MU)

    # Component 1
    # Sum over the alts
    p1_3d = v_mu_3d / v_mu_3d.sum(axis=1)[:,None,:]

    # Component 2
    # Sum over the alts
    num = v_mu_3d.sum(axis=1)
    # Divide over alts by MU for each nest
    num = np.where(MU > 0, num[:, None, :] / MU, 0)
    # Sum over the nests
    p2_3d = num / num.sum(axis=2)[:, :, None]

    p = p1_3d * p2_3d
    p = p.sum(axis=2)

    # Pass a 2d matrix of probabilities to the main function (rows x alts)
    return p
def bc_mod(params):
    LOC_PROB = loc_probs(params)
    LP_BR = np.log(LOC_PROB)
    llfun = chosen_spar.multiply(LP_BR)
    llfun = llfun.sum()
    return -1 * llfun

# Run minimization
res = minimize(bc_mod, params, method='BFGS', options = {'maxiter':1,'disp': True})
print(res.x)
```

Comment: Can you show the version with the loops, for comparison?

Comment: Is it possible to pull this function out and run it in a script that just constructs `params` statically and calls this function, then profile that? Because there's clearly other stuff going on in that profile dump that's unrelated here. Which _shouldn't_ be preventing us from seeing how the 1.461s per `loc_procs` breaks down, but it does seem to be anyway.

Comment: Also, given that you can see your higher-level code and we can't: is calling this function 2703 times what you expected and wanted?

Comment: Yeah, that 2703 number is pretty suspicious, considering how you say "3 iterations" several times.

Comment: I've tried to simply the code it runs so it's just pulling data in and calling the function once. The function is called from scipy.minimize using BFGS. I'm not sure about the internals of the minimization routine, but it is correct for it to call loc_prob() several times per iteration. The remaining code is data prep, which runs once and is fairly well optimized.

Comment: What are the types and shapes of all these objects? It looks like you're using `np.matrix` objects for at least some of your data.

Comment: Most are numpy arrays with float32 data types. The dimensions of most are (20738, 31, 14), MU is (31, 14). It basically takes (20738, 31, 14) arrays and does a series of operations to sum/multiply/divide over dimensions.

Comment: What is `NEST_LEN`? What are `arr_nest` and `sp_arr_nest`?  What is `v_3d`?  If they are numpy arrays, what are their shapes? It would be easier to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added a minimal example with settings for the minimization set to 1 iteration. It takes about 5 minutes to run it, on my machine but that will vary widely depending on the machine and the random numbers generated. We generally change the parameters after an initial estimation to increase speed, but this is an initial run so I have little clue what they should be.